# How to force the Plugin on Post-Operation to Submit?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin in post-operation witch need to create a folder on sharepoint via webservice, to do that, my plugin calls a webservice to execute a FechXML to get the info from the entity, but the problem is that entity still not exist, and it give me Null.

How do i force the plugin to submit/save the data to my FechXml to work?

PLUGIN CODE:

```cs
try
    {
        Entity entity;
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            if (entity.LogicalName != "fcg_processos")
            {

                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Ocorreu um erro no PlugIn Create Folder.");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Ocorreu um erro no PlugIn Create Folder.");
        }

        processosid = (Guid)((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"])["fcg_processosid"];
        string processoid2 = processosid.ToString();


        PluginSharepointProcessos.ServiceReference.PrxActivityResult result = log.CreateFolderSP("Processo", processoid2);

        string resultado = result.xmlContent;

        if (result.retCode > 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Ocorreu um erro na criação do Folder do Processo.");

        }
```

WEBSERVICE CODE:

```cs
 {          
            //WEBSERVICE TO CALL XML FROM ENTITY
            PrxActivityResult Processo = ProcessoFetch2("", "", guid);
            string stxml;
            stxml = Processo.XmlContent;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(stxml);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("resultset/result");
            List<string[]> lista = new List<string[]>();
            string[] strs = new string[7];
            if (nodeList.Count != 0)//verificar o numero de registos
            {

                foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in nodeList)
                {
                    if (xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("//fcg_numero") != null)
                        strs[2] = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("//fcg_numero").InnerText;
                    else
                        strs[2] = "";

                    if (xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("//Concurso.fcg_numero") != null)
                        strs[3] = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("//Concurso.fcg_numero").InnerText;
                    else
                        strs[3] = "";
                }

            }

        IwsspClient FmwSharepoint = new IwsspClient();
        PrxActivityResult folderresult = new PrxActivityResult();

        List<ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave> arrayfields = new List<ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave>();

        ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave nprocesso = new ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave();
        nprocesso.Key = "FCG_Numero_Processo";
        nprocesso.value = strs[2];
        arrayfields.Add(nprocesso);

        ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave npconcurso = new ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave();
        npconcurso.Key = "FCG_Numero_Concurso";
        npconcurso.value = strs[3];
        arrayfields.Add(npconcurso);

        ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave npguid = new ws.fcg.sipp.svc.ServiceReferenceSharePoint.PareChave();
        npguid.Key = "FCG_Guid_CRM";
        npguid.value = guid;
        arrayfields.Add(npguid);

        folderresult = FmwSharepoint.CreateFolder("http://localhost/folder", "Processos", strs[2], arrayfields.ToArray());

        res = folderresult;
        }
```

Comment: If you are doing a post-operation on an entity, by definition it is after the transaction.  Also if you are retrieving data from the current entity you have the plugin on you should just grab that data from the context & pre/post images so you don't have to make an additional call.  If you show your code it will also be easier for others to help as well.

Comment: I just edit the post with the code.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you actually perform the FetchXml Query.  Is that in the ProcessoFetch2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a plugin runs on the Post-Operation, it is still within the database transaction, and it hasn't actually been committed to the database.  Any calls done with the service reference passed in as a part of the Plugin Context will be executed within the context on the database transaction and you will be able to retrieve the newly created/updated values.  If you create a brand new OrganizationServiceProxy (Which I'm guessing is what you're doing), it will execute outside of the database transaction, and will not see the newly created / updated values.

As @AndyMeyers suggests in his comment (which really should be an answer IMHO), grabbing the data from the plugin context either via a pre/post image or the target is ideal since it eliminates another database call.  If you're having to lookup records that may have been created by another plugin that fired earlier, you'll need to use the IOrganizationService that is included in the plugin context.

Comment: +1 for correcting me that the post plugin still being in the transaction.  In the previous version of CRM (4.0) this wasn't true and I think I got my wires mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I had no option and I used this code to run webservice based on image and forget the FecthXml, as mentioned, i get all info from the Image on the post operation and send back to the WebService. Thanks, here is the code:

```
 entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            concursid = (Guid)entity.Attributes["fcg_concursid"];
            guid = concursid.ToString();

            string npconcurs = (string)entity.Attributes["fcg_numer"];
            nconcurs= npconcurs;

            EntityReference nprograma = (EntityReference)entity.Attributes["fcg_unidadeorganica"];

            program = nprogram.Name;

            if (entity.LogicalName != "fcg_concurs")
```